# setting the name of an AbstractType in a contact form for PHPUnit

Tags: symfony, twig, phpunit, symfony-forms

I'm trying to PHPUnit test a method for a contact form

```
public function testContact()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit')->form();

    $form['blogbundle_enquirytype[name]']       = 'name';
    // other form field assignments here

    $crawler = $client->submit($form);

    $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('.blogger-notice:contains("Your contact enquiry was successfully sent. Thank you!")')->count());
}
```

PHPUnit doesn't recognize `blogbundle_enquirytype` (Unreachable field) presumably because the controller instantiates it like this

```
$enquiry = new Enquiry();
$form = $this->createForm(EnquiryType::class, $enquiry);
```

So despite the `AbstractType`:

```
class EnquiryType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('email', EmailType::class);
    $builder->add('subject');
    $builder->add('body', TextareaType::class);
}

public function getName(){
    return 'blogbundle_enquirytype';
}
```

Is there another way to set the name of the `EnquiryType`, or a way for Phpunit to identify the form?

Here is the form

```
<form action="/contact" method="post"  class="blogger">

    <div><label for="enquiry_name" class="required">Name</label><input type="text" id="enquiry_name" name="enquiry[name]" required="required" maxlength="255" /></div>
    <div><label for="enquiry_email" class="required">Email</label><input type="email" id="enquiry_email" name="enquiry[email]" required="required" /></div>
    <div><label for="enquiry_subject" class="required">Subject</label><input type="text" id="enquiry_subject" name="enquiry[subject]" required="required" maxlength="50" /></div>
    <div><label for="enquiry_body" class="required">Body</label><textarea id="enquiry_body" name="enquiry[body]" required="required"></textarea></div>

    <input type="hidden" id="enquiry__token" name="enquiry[_token]" value="-eZq7Go6ELXykluf0Fca_CPvzeB3yEUj2yuOnyamYBU" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: check the page generated is a valid html form: a non missing closed tag can hang the selector.

Comment: check you have only one form in your page also: you select a button named submit, are you sure you have only one?

Comment: @Matteo good ideas. 1. I ran `var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent())` and put the phpunit output into `validator.w3.org` but there are no errors on the page or form. 2. There is only one submit button on the page

Comment: Could the problem be the way EntityType is created? So at present it is `$form = $this->createForm(EnquiryType::class, $enquiry)`, while a prior version (not working) has `$form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry)`

Comment: I don't think is a problem related with the form creation. If you try the page is working fine? If you inspect the html you find the correct element?

Comment: @Matteo I've added the form HTML. The page works and I can submit a query through the contact form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$form['enquiry[name]']       = 'name';
```

instead of:

```
$form['blogbundle_enquirytype[name]']       = 'name';
```

**UPDATE:**

Regarding to the [migration guide](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form) to the symfony3:

> The getBlockPrefix() method was added to the FormTypeInterface in
>   replacement of the getName() method which has been removed.

So you can continue to use your code of the testing class if you change the form method from this:

```
    /**
     * Returns the prefix of the template block name for this type.
     *
     * The block prefix defaults to the underscored short class name with
     * the "Type" suffix removed (e.g. "UserProfileType" => "user_profile").
     *
     * @return string The prefix of the template block name
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix(){
    return 'blogbundle_enquirytype';
}
```

instead of this:

```
public function getName(){
    return 'blogbundle_enquirytype';
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I was sure I'd done this before, but I must've missed the wood for the trees. Thanks!